# how to call a specific function on every ajax request

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I have a problem, that I have several pages in my project and I used a lot of ajax requests in my project, but now I think that whenever an ajax request is called a function will called and whenever that request ends another function will call. How can I do this globally I know I can put this in every ajax request but I need a solution which I do in one place and it works all over the project.

```
$(document).read(function(){
 // Suppose this document load function is written on layout page and every page is  inherited from this page
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/), for example

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {
        console.log('test');
    },
    complete: function() {
        console.log('completed');
    }
});
```

will setup `beforeSend` handler for **every** ajax request. Note that `ajaxSetup` can take any option that `$.ajax` can.

Comment: its done before send , but what should i write if i want to call a function on complete of ajax request ?

Comment: You should write it at the very begining of JS file (before any AJAX call). You may want to fire AJAX requests before document is ready, so there's no reason for putting this inside `$(document).ready(...);`.

Comment: @freakish what if my ajax already has a complete function? It will call both handlers? Or only one?

Comment: @Guilherme `complete` on `$.ajax` overrides the one on `$.ajaxSetup` and so only the one from `$.ajax` will be called.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a wrapper function for your ajax, then use that function. that way, you have "central" control over the ajax call. something like:

```
//fast and crude way to extend jQuery
$.fn.customAjax = function(params){

    //contains defaults and predefined functions
    var defaults = {
        complete : function(){...default complete hander...},
        beforeSend : function (){...default beforeSend handler}
        ...
    }

    //merge settings
    var finalParams = $.extend({},defaults,params);

    //call ajax and return the deferred
    return $.ajax(finalParams);
}

//use it like
$.customAjax({
   url : ...,
   method : ...,
   data: ...,
   complete : function(){...} //redefining in the call will override the defaults
});
```

Comment: Nice! Good to see you took care of deferred too by using return.

Answer (score 1):

.ajaxStart

Register a handler to be called when the first Ajax request begins.

.ajaxSucess

Attach a function to be executed whenever an Ajax request completes successfully.

for Detail doc:
    http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() { 
   $.ajax({
     url: "anotherMethod.html",
     context: document.body
   });
});
});
```

That means whenever ajax call completed successfully call your desire call.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have a bug when complete. Click on Like, if work for you

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqXHR, settings) {
    $('#general-ajax-load ').fadeIn();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, jqXHR, settings) {
    $('#general-ajax-load ').fadeOut();
});
```